# how to run this python code to get out this result?

Tags: python

I am newbie with python and studying python at "fluent python" book, they gave me this code:

```
import collections
Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])
class FrenchDeck:
ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()
def __init__(self):
self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
for rank in self.ranks]
def __len__(self):
return len(self._cards)
def __getitem__(self, position):
return self._cards[position]
```

And they said to me that if I ran this code, I can have this in the console:

```
>>> beer_card = Card('7', 'diamonds')
>>> beer_card
Card(rank='7', suit='diamonds')
```

or this in the console

```
>>> deck = FrenchDeck()
>>> len(deck)
52
```

But when I tried to ran the code, they gave me this error:

```
File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\自分のこと\Python\test35.py", line 4
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after class definition on line 3
PS C:\Users\HP>
```

Could you please tell me how can I solve the problem? Or what is exactly they want to do with the code?
Thank you very much for your time.

I want to know exactly what they want to do with the code I wrote in the text.

Comment: Indentation (i.e. space at the beginning of a line) is important and relevant in Python. Your code doesn't have that, even in spaces where it's definitely needed (the actual code of a method after a `def ` line needs to be indented, for example. So make sure you copy the code *exactly*, including the leading space from where you got it.

Comment: Do not edit whitespace of Python code in a question; the edit I rolled back *removed* the very problem being asked about.

Answer (score 0):

In Python your code has to be indented in order to define blocks (in other languages like Java, JS, C#,..., those would be defined with curly brackets {}).

Your code should then look like this :

```py
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
            for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

Comment: thanks, but when I ran the code, I still do not have the result like I wrote ? How can they have the "beer_card = Card('7', diamonds) ..." ?

Comment: Look at this repro I did : https://stackblitz.com/edit/secret-python-manawe?file=main.py  You get the expected result in the console. I guess you are confused between the Python program, the console and the Python shell. In your question, the lines starting with ">>>" are executed in the Python shell. That means that you have to open a terminal and run "python", then you will see those ">>>" and you can run Python commands